# Quick primer on implementing a COM object that implement some custom IDLs in python?

Tags: python, com

Does anyone have experience using python to create a COM object that implements some custom IDLs?

Basically I'd like to know if it's extremely simple to do compared to c++, and if it is do you know of a good tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you are looking for is in the [Python Programming On Win32](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926219/) book, by Mark Hammond and Andy Robinson. A bit old, and the COM object creation info is distributed across some chapters.

A more recent example, [simple COM server using Python](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/03/calling-python-from-maxscript.html), can give you a quick start.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [comtypes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes), which allows to access and implement custom interfaces.  An article on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/python-comtypes-interop.aspx) has a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check [Advance COM](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html) a free chapter from Python Programming On Win32 mentioned by gimel.